# Combining clustering algorithms in MapReduce

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, k-means

For my college project, I initially thought to implement a combined clustering algorithm on MapReduce. I have finished with KMeans. Now my questions are:

1. Can any other clustering algorithm be combined with Kmeans on MapReduce? If so, which algorithm and what is the procedure?
2. If combining is not possible, how can enhancement to existing KMeans be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a method to intelligently select initial centroids rather selecting them randomly.

There are papers on improved K-Means algorithm. You can refer one or more of them and create your own improved K-Means algorithm.